# How can i change storyboard speed programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, storyboard

I have a storyboard in my WPF application. In storyboard, I have a lot of animation. After begin storyboard, I want to set storyboard current speed

According to my search, I have to use below code.

```
storyboard.SpeedRatio=New Speed;
```

With the above code, Storyboard speed is changing. But the storyboard should end so I can see this effect. I want to change storyboard speed real time.

Answer (score -1):

i found the solution of my problem. You can use below code for change speed of storyboard real time

```
 storyboard.SetSpeedRatio(this,newSpeed);
```

This code works clearly.